# Best Way to Integrate Scala Test into Existing Netbeans Java Project?

Tags: java, scala, netbeans, scalatest

I have a stand-alone application that I wrote before I became test-infected.  Its a Netbeans gui project, so I depend upon Matisse, and I don't want to change that, at least not now.

I would, however, like to build the unit test coverage up, and I'd like to take this opportunity to learn some Scala.

So what I would like to do is create tests in scala.  I understand that this is possible because Scala Test has a junit runner.  I think I could hack on the ant and eventually make it work, but I think that would be sort of a "pound until it fits" scenario.  I have searched Stack Overflow, and there are similar questions, but not quite the same topic.

Has anybody done this before?  If so, please let me know how.  Thanks!

Comment: Upon further reflection, I think its a more general problem. i.e. How would you integrate tests written in any other language, not just Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My experience is with Maven Java projects in NetBeans and the Specs testing framework, so I don't know if this will be helpful or of interest to you. But I hope it can serve as a starting point to solving your specific problem.

In any event, here's a detailed blog post I did on setting up Specs in Maven to test Java web services: http://janxspirit.blogspot.com/2011/01/sneaking-scala-through-alley-test-java.html

Good luck!